How to do this integral numerically in $O(N)$?
Consider a region $V$ with finite volume, and bounded smooth function $g: \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ and a kernel $K$, and define $f: \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ by:
$$
f(\mathbf x) = \int_V K(\mathbf x, \mathbf x')g(\mathbf x')\;d^3\mathbf x'
$$
Assume I have the discretized form of the function $g$, in a structured grid of $N$ points, and I want the find the discretized version of $f$ in that grid.
The Kernel is of this form:
$$
K(\mathbf x, \mathbf x') = \frac{1}{|\mathbf x - \mathbf x'|^p}
$$
Where $p\ge 1$ a natural number.

A way would be to simply use straightforward numerical integration, but that would slow: $O(N^2)$.
I am seeking a solution which is $O(N)$ or $O(N\log N)$, or at least, subquadratic, because $N$ in this case is too large (say, $N\sim 10^9$).
How to do it?
If you have references that you think it would help, let me know. I couldn't find any.

Do you know about the Fast Multipole Method? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_multipole_method

@StefanLafon I don't. Thank you! I'll be looking into that right now!

A quick $N\log N$ method is using Fourier transform if $\widehat{K(x)}$ exists since your kernel is convolutional. Another famous one is the Barne-Hut algorithm, you can find it as a fast multipole method without "multipole-multipole" interactions.
